# What does "果布" mean?

Tags: meaning

そのころ、この広州は南海貿易のもっとも殷賑をきわめた港であった。古く漢代に番禺と呼ばれていたころから、この港には犀角、象牙、瑇瑁、珠璣、翡翠、琥珀、沈香、銀、銅、**果布**が多くあつまり．．．
What is **果布**? (from 澁澤龍彦『高丘親王航海記』）

Answer (score 1):

Found some evidence from internet that `果布` means [Dipterocarpaceae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dipterocarpaceae)

- [The Indonesian Word (果布) in the Chinese Texts (史記) and (漢書)](http://ci.nii.ac.jp/els/110008004516.pdf?id=ART0009595481&type=pdf&lang=en&host=cinii&order_no=&ppv_type=0&lang_sw=&no=1472215371&cp=)
- [“果布”是马来语呼龙脑香“果布婆律”的音译。](http://www.gzsdfz.org.cn/qnsd/smxz/201608/t20160804_51819.html)(Chinese)

Comment: I can't read the Chinese link, but the first study says "[果布] should be considered as meaning ... camphor, the highly-prized aromatic substance native to the southern regions". Which is only tangentially related to dipterocarpaceae (in that it can be harvested from a species of it, but also from other sources). I think camphor fits the above text more accurately, as well. I think it should be noted that 果布 had been (according to the study's thesis) incorrectly translated as 'fruits and linen', and the author of the extract may have drawn upon this supposed usage in classical Chinese writing.